# RAID: Switched from W2K12 Hyper-V to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, raid, windows-server-2012-r2

Until yesterday I was using Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V. I had two RAID sets: one 600GB (2 disks) and one 3TB (2 disks).

The first was connected to Windows Server. The second was passed through to an Ubuntu Server VM running on the W2K12 machine.

I figured that if I installed Ubuntu instead of Windows as the host OS, the RAID disks would be found by the new OS. But this didn't work as excpected. The RAID sets are being seen by Ubuntu, but they are completely the wrong sizes. The 3TB set is seen as 750GB. the 650GB set is seen as 580GB.

What can I do to repair this error? I would like to save my data and have the RAID sets connected in their original sizes.

Thank you!

Dani